# Floating point arithmetic error propagation

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point, error-propagation

I have a function $$y=ln(\frac{x_1}{x_2})$$, $$x_1, x_2 > 1$$ and two ways to calculate it:

1. $$v = \frac{x_1}{x_2} => y_1=ln(v)$$
2. $$v_1 = ln(x_1)$$
   $$v_2 = ln(x_2)$$
   $$y_2 = v_1 - v_2$$

How error is propagated and how it affects end result? Which way is better?

Comment: That depends on the typical relative sizes of $x_1$,$x_2$ and to some extent on how your approximation of $\ln$ is implemented. However there is definitely a regime where the first method is better, can you see what it is?